# Wordpress & MySQL table fragmentation

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, innodb, database-fragmentation

So, I'm using Wordpress, MySQL (8.0.16), InnoDB.
The `wp_options` table normally is 13 MB. The problem is, it suddenly (at least within a span of a few days) becomes 27 GB and then stops growing, because there's no more space available. Those 27 GB are considered data, not indexes.

Dumping and importing the table gives you a table of the normal size. The number of entries is around 4k, the autoincrement index is 200k+. Defragmenting table with `ALTER TABLE wp_options ENGINE = InnoDB;` changes the table size on disk to normal, but mysql thinks otherwise, even after the server restart.

```
+------------+------------+
| Table      | Size in MB |
+------------+------------+
| wp_options |   26992.56 |
+------------+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

MySQL logs don't say much:

```
2019-08-05T17:02:41.939945Z 1110933 [ERROR] [MY-012144] [InnoDB] posix_fallocate(): Failed to preallocate data for file ./XXX/wp_options.ibd, desired size 4194304 bytes. Operating system error number 28. Check that the disk is not full or a disk quota exceeded. Make sure the file system supports this function. Some operating system error numbers are described at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/operating-system-error-codes.html
2019-08-05T17:02:41.941604Z 1110933 [Warning] [MY-012637] [InnoDB] 1048576 bytes should have been written. Only 774144 bytes written. Retrying for the remaining bytes.
2019-08-05T17:02:41.941639Z 1110933 [Warning] [MY-012638] [InnoDB] Retry attempts for writing partial data failed.
2019-08-05T17:02:41.941655Z 1110933 [ERROR] [MY-012639] [InnoDB] Write to file ./XXX/wp_options.ibd failed at offset 28917628928, 1048576 bytes should have been written, only 774144 were written. Operating system error number 28. Check that your OS and file system support files of this size. Check also that the disk is not full or a disk quota exceeded.
2019-08-05T17:02:41.941673Z 1110933 [ERROR] [MY-012640] [InnoDB] Error number 28 means 'No space left on device'
```

My guess is that something starts adding options (something transient-related, maybe?) and never stops.

The question is, how to debug it? Any help/hints would be appreciated.

Hourly Cron to defragment looks like a very bad solution.

### UPD:

1 day had passed, free disk space decreased by 7 GB. Current autoincrement index is 206975 (and it was 202517 yesterday when there were 27 GB free). So 4.5K entries = 7 GB, I guess?

```
mysql> SELECT table_name AS `Table`, round(((data_length + index_length) / 1024 / 1024), 2) `Size in MB` FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE table_schema = 'XXX' AND table_name = 'wp_options';
+------------+------------+
| Table      | Size in MB |
+------------+------------+
| wp_options |    7085.52 |
+------------+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)


mysql> select ENGINE, TABLE_NAME,Round( DATA_LENGTH/1024/1024) as data_length , round(INDEX_LENGTH/1024/1024) as index_length, round(DATA_FREE/ 1024/1024) as data_free from information_schema.tables  where  DATA_FREE > 0 and TABLE_NAME = "wp_options" limit 0, 10;
+--------+------------+-------------+--------------+-----------+
| ENGINE | TABLE_NAME | data_length | index_length | data_free |
+--------+------------+-------------+--------------+-----------+
| InnoDB | wp_options |        7085 |            0 |         5 |
+--------+------------+-------------+--------------+-----------+
```

I will monitor the dynamics of how free space decreases, maybe that would shed some more light on the problem.

### UPD (final)

I had a feeling it was something stupid, and I was right. There was a `flush_rewrite_rules();` of all things unholy right in the `functions.php`. Examining the general log was helpful.

Comment: Have you tried with [slow log](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/slow-query-log.html)? That might give you some hint where all the queries come from.

Comment: @Mischa Nothing special is the slow log

Comment: @Mischa please post this as an answer and I will approve it. I should have checked general log earlier.

Comment: ok :) https://stackoverflow.com/a/57476395/3900251

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried with [slow log](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/slow-query-log.html)? That might give you some hint where all the queries come from.

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is that you're seeing incorrect statistics about the table size.

MySQL 8.0 tries to cache the statistics about tables, but there seem to be some bugs in the implementation. Sometimes it shows table statistics as NULL, and sometimes it shows values, but fails to update them as you modify table data.

See https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=83957 for example, a bug that discusses the problems with this caching behavior.

You can disable the caching. It may cause queries against the INFORMATION_SCHEMA or SHOW TABLE STATUS to be a little bit slower, but I would guess it's no worse than in versions of MySQL before 8.0.

```
SET GLOBAL information_schema_stats_expiry = 0;
```

The integer value is the number of seconds MySQL keeps statistics cached. If you query the table stats, you may see old values from the cache, until they expire and MySQL refreshes them by reading from the storage engine.

The default value for the cache expiration is 86400, or 24 hours. That seems excessive.

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_information_schema_stats_expiry

If you think Wordpress is writing to the table, then it might be. You can enable the binary log or the query log to find out. Or just observe `SHOW PROCESSLIST` for a few minutes.

You might have a wordpress plugin that is updating or inserting into a table frequently. You can look for the latest update_time:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
ORDER BY UPDATE_TIME DESC LIMIT 3;
```

Watch this to find out which tables are written to most recently.

There are caveats to this UPDATE_TIME stat. It isn't always in sync with the queries that updated the table, because writes to tablespace files are asynchronous. Read about it here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/tables-table.html

Comment: Thanks for response, but my main problem is that it actually grows huge, not only appears to be 26 GB. 1 day had passed, free disk space decreased by 7 GB. Current autoincrement index is 206975 (and it was 202517 yesterday when there were 27 GB free)

Comment: I thought that might be caused by a ton of entries being dumped into wp_options, but it does not look like it's the case

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a staging site, and is the problem replicated there?  If so, then turn off all plugins (as long as turning off the plugin doesn't break your site) on your staging site to see if the problem stops.  If it does, then turn them on again one at a time to  find out which plugin is causing the problem.

If you don't have a staging site, then you can try doing this on live, but keep in mind you will be messing with your live functionality (generally not recommended).  In this case, just remove the plugins you absolutely do not need, and hopefully one of them is the culprit.  If this works, then add them one at a time again until you find the plugin causing the problem.

---

My suggestion above assumes a plugin is causing this problem.  Out of the box WordPress doesn't do this (not that I've heard of).  It's possible there is custom programming doing this, but you would need to let us know more details concerning any recent scripts.

The biggest problem at this point is that you don't know what the problem is.  Until you do, it's hard to take corrective measures.

Answer (score 1):

Some plugins fail to clean up after themselves.  Chase down what plugin(s) you added about the time the problem started.  Look in the rows in `options` to see if there are clues that further implicate specific plugins.

No, nothing is MySQL's statistics, etc, can explain a 27GB 'error' in the calculations.  No amount of `OPTIMIZE TABLE`, etc will fix more than a fraction of that.  You need to delete most of the rows.  Show us some of the recent rows (high `AUTO_INCREMENT` ids).

Comment: The thing is, the amount of content in the table is ok. So If I dump that table it gives me a small file of 4.9 MB

Comment: My guess was that something was aggressively inderting and deleting stuff into wp_options. Now the AUTO_INCREMENT id is 221674 somaring to 202517 at the beginning. Since then, I've defragmented the table at least twice and it grew by at least 34 gb in total.

Comment: @AlexanderMikhalchenko  If you want to find the problem, do as Rick James suggests and track down the plugin that likely is causing the issue.  Going after a MySQL solution is going after the symptom, not the problem.  How do you troubleshoot the problem?  Read my answer (and you can also apply Rick's answer to if you recall what plugin was installed at that time).

Comment: @Jarom thanks for feedback, there are no plugins that I could disable now in prod. I have my suspicions because there's a similar woocommerce setup which does not have this problem. I've been collecting the data on disk usage to compare it with the website activity and hours, will check it tonight

Answer (score 0):

If the table has frequent delete/update/insert, you can run OPTIMIZE TABLE yourTable;

It needs to be run in maintenance window.

It will free spaces for reuse, but disk space will not be decreased.

Comment: I would like to fix the issue rather than run that on cron each week. This is what you are proposing, I believe?

Comment: If the fragmentation is caused by frequent delete/update/insert, it is not something you can fix unless you change the design of your app. This type of maintenance is unavoidable to some hot spot tables, and usually be done by a DBA